# Haskell Couldn't match expected type 'String' with actual type 'Char'

Tags: string, haskell, char

I am wondering why I'm getting this error.  It's for an assignment where i'm to convert from an integer to a hex value.  I call this helper conversion function when I mod the integer value by `16`.  (concatenated with the integer value which I then divide by `16` in a recursive call)

**Here is my code:**

```
    changeToHex :: Integer -> String
    --main function

    toHex :: Integer -> String
    toHex x
        |x == 0         = '0'
        |x == 1         = '1'
        |x == 2         = '2'
        |x == 3         = '3'
        |x == 4         = '4'
        |x == 5         = '5'
        |x == 6         = '6'
        |x == 7         = '7'
        |x == 8         = '8'
        |x == 9         = '9'
        |x == 10        = 'A'
        |x == 11        = 'B'
        |x == 12        = 'C'
        |x == 13        = 'D'
        |x == 14        = 'E'
        |x == 15        = 'F'
```

Comment: can you post the whole error message?

Answer (score 11):

Using single quotes (`'F'`) gives you a `Char` literal. For a `String` literal, which is in fact a list of `Char` values, you should use double quotes (`"F"`).

Since `String` is an alias for `[Char]`, if you want to convert from a `Char` to a `String`, you can merely wrap the `Char` in a one-element list. A function to do so might look like:

```
stringFromChar :: Char -> String
stringFromChar x = [x]
```

This is typically written inline, as `(:[])`, equivalent to `\x -> (x : [])` or `\x -> [x]`.

As an aside, you can simplify your code considerably, using for example the `Enum` typeclass:

```
toHexDigit :: Int -> Char
toHexDigit x
  | x < 0 = error "toHex: negative digit value"
  | x < 10 = toEnum $ fromEnum '0' + x
  | x < 15 = toEnum $ fromEnum 'A' + x - 10
  | otherwise = error "toHex: digit value too large"
```

More generally, any time you have a function like:

```
f x
  | x == A = ...
  | x == B = ...
  | x == C = ...
  ...
```

You can convert that to a less repetitious, more efficient equivalent with `case`:

```
f x = case x of
  A -> ...
  B -> ...
  C -> ...
  ...
```

Comment: Okay that's what I thought but then I get an error in my main function saying "couldn't match expected type 'Char' with actual type 'String' ".  So odd, I don't mention Char anywhere...

Comment: @johnstamos: `String` is defined in terms of `Char`, as `type String = [Char]`.